# Is there any way to view full podcast title on my iPhone running iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, podcasts

Most of the time the podcast title is long and it is truncated with dots at the end.
I think since iPhone OS 3.?, title font size has gotten smaller so I can see more of the title.
However, I still can't view the full title.

Is there any way to view full podcast title?

I'm on iOS 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way, Though a bit strange.

If you choose to delete the podcast/file, you will get a Confirmation dialog with Delete/Cancel option.

1. Slide with your finger horizontal
   over the file and it will give you
   an option to Delete the file.
2. Choose Delete to show the second Confirmation dialog. There, you will be able to view the full name of the Podcast.

Be CAREFUL not to choose Delete or you will loose the file. And also the full name of the podcast.

Comment: Nice! +1 for that. Now we only still need to see the full title before downloading an episode directly with the iPhone/iPod with iTunes. Any ideas, Nike2? ;)

Comment: I have not found any way to see the full title yet when downloading. For that I use iTunes. =/

Comment: Thanks. Seems like this is the only way to see full title for now. And it appears that Apple's aware of this 'full title' issue on iPod app. I don't think it shows confirmation for swipe to delete in any other Apple apps like mail and messages. Hopefully they will do something different like auto scrolling text on following iOS updates.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Podcast view doesn't support Cover View browsing until after you've chosen an episode, but if you've chosen an episode and it still isn't completely shown in the titlebar, rotate your device to landscape.

[image: Landscape iPod View - Cover Flow View]

Here's what the normal view looks like, notice how the title is not complete in the title bar.

[image: Standard iPod (Track) View]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not, there is no detail view for podcasts in iPhone's Itunes store, I think your best option is to check them on the desktop version of Itunes.

I tried searching the app store, and no luck finding an "app for that".

Answer (score 0):

On iOS4, you can see the full title when listening to or watching it.  Simply touch the screen, and it toggles between showing the controls and showing the full title and description.

I haven't found a way of seeing the full title without actually starting the podcast.

Comment: I only see description. I don't see full title on my iOS 4.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS4 itunes there's no way to view full title before downloading that I can find. It's such a basic requirement that you'd have thought it *must* be possible to view it somehow. But no. iTunes doesn't even appear to have a settings page anywhere - it's just perfect the way it ships. Apple: how about just allowing the text to wrap to the next line? Not so neat looking but an improvement on the current abysmal UX.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5 you can see the full title of the podcast by tapping and holding on the individual  podcast.  Don't know if that works in iOS 4.