# How can I read full song title on my iPod touch or iPhone?

Tags: ios, music

When I play or select songs on my iPod touch 4G I often can not read the full title of the song when it is very long. In all views (Coverflow front, coverflow back, now playing portrait mode, playlist) it is always truncated. Especially for classical music this is really annoying because the titles are something in the lines of "Beethoven: The Complete String Quartetts" -  "String Quartett #3 in D Op. 18/3 - 1. Allegro". Is there some trick to view the **complete** title?

Comment: This has been an annoyance since at least iPhone OS 2.0. It would be nice if the title scrolled like it did on iPods as far back as I can remember.

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1912/is-there-any-way-to-view-full-podcast-title-on-iphone/

Comment: I seem to recall hearing this was fixed in iOS 5.0. Can't find a reference for it, though...

Comment: Besides the horizontal positioning of the ipod or alternate viewings of song titles such as portrait, etc. the longest space that I have found to let me see the song title is to press the home button twice when the lock screen is displayed. This brings up volume and pause options aswell as a title space about 9 letters longer that horizontal view. However, I Still can't see the movement's tempo marking for my Glenn Gould Schoenberg piano conerto or the composer's name! What if I forgot who composed one of the the piano sonatas on a multi-composer album? First world problems...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of iOS 5, this problem is even simpler. Many views will scroll overflowing information, but you can also simply tap and hold on many sources of text in order to view them in a significantly smaller font size in a back pop-up tooltip, which greatly expands the amount of text that can be fit in the width of the iPhone's screen size.

Note that my previous answer still applies (below), but this tooltip is usually quite a bit faster and much more direct.

---

For all iOS versions before iOS 5:

My answer on the [View Full Podcast Title](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1912/is-there-any-way-to-view-full-podcast-title-on-iphone/9688#9688) Question covers this as well. You can use Cover Flow view (rotate your device to Landscape while in the iPod/Music app after selecting a song) in order to greatly increase the amount of room used to display song information.

Your title is particularly large, I don't know what the landscape/Cover Flow view limit is. I don't have any songs that exceed it yet :).

Comment: The above example already exceeds it (Album: "Beethoven: The Complete String Quartetts" Track: "String Quartett #3 in D Op. 18/3 - 1. Allegro"). In classic land there is a lot like that.

Comment: I'm reasonably well versed in the formal titles for Classical compositions :). Cover View is the widest display canvas I know of, if for no other reason than by the obvious fact that your device is horizontal. If it's too big for that, then I'm afraid that's as good as it gets without perhaps a dedicated Music Display third-party app.

Comment: That question is about podcast episodes, which you can delete on a whim. This question is about normal songs, which you cannot swipe to delete, so, you can't use that method. Not to even mention how bad of an idea it is to go to delete something if you don't intend to. I deleted a podcast episode on accident just testing the answer!